# Next Auth Firebase Auth acessToken

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

I have a private next project with Next Auth and I am implementing credentials only email and password because these users will be created at the Firebase Auth panel. My Next Auth seems like this:

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { auth, app } from '@/util/firebase';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';

export default NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            credentials.email,
            credentials.password
          );

          // I want to get this token and save as Bearer Authorization token userCredential.idToken

          if (userCredential.user) return { email: userCredential.user.email };
          else return null;
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

But there is a little problem. For the requests API, I need to send a valid Bearer token. How can I store and retrieve the token?

Observation: Token is available in `userCredential.idToken`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of next-auth is to store the user data in a protected session 
So first you have to return from the `authorize` method what you want to store in you session :

```js
async authorize(credentials, req) {
  
    //...
    if (userCredential) {
        return {
            email: userCredential.user.email,
            accessToken: userCredential.idToken
            //... any other keys you want to include in the returned object
        }
    }
    else return null;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
  }
}
```

Next you need to store these data in your session, to do so, you have to use callbacks :

> **JWT callback**
> This callback is called whenever a JSON Web Token is created (i.e. at sign in) or updated (i.e whenever a session is accessed in the client). The returned value will be encrypted, and it is stored in a cookie.

> **Session callback**
> The session callback is called whenever a session is checked. By default, only a subset of the token is returned for increased security. If you want to make something available you added to the token (like access_token and user.id from above) via the jwt() callback, you have to explicitly forward it here to make it available to the client.

Likely, the object returned by the `authorize` method is available as parameter named `user` in the jwt callback, so you get advantage of this latter to update the token and return it
Then the object returned by the jwt callback is available in the session callback as parameter named `token` so again you use this token to update the session

```js
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ user, token }) {
      //   update token if user is returned
      if (user) {
        token.email = user.email;
        token.accessToken= user.accessToken;

      }
      //   return final_token
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token}) {
      //  update session from token
      session.email = token.email;
      session.accessToken= token.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
  },
```

You now have your session including the information you wanted to store.

So from the client side you can access it using [useSession()](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession)

```js
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
const Home = () => {
const session = useSession();
const myAccessToken = session.data.accessToken;
//...
}
```

See also [getServerSession()](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getserversession)

Comment: This approach makes sense to pass the accessToken through the session, but will this accessToken be automatically refreshed like it would if we were using the signInWithEmailAndPassword() in the client like it is meant to be used? Because once it expires we will be getting 401 errors and have to login again

Comment: I still have this doubt. If i am not wrong, this will not be updated :(