# NextJs credentials authentication with protected routes with next-auth

Tags: reactjs, security, next.js, next-auth

I am currently developing a web application using NextJs (13.1.1). On the other side, an external backend has been provided to me, in order to be able to connect (username/password), and get an access token, a refresh token (and its expiration, but not in a cookie) in response body, in order to be able to use the different routes of this backend. I then created my own system to refresh my access token (with a react context), and a component to protect my pages that need authentication, but some pages, because of my guard system can take several seconds to load, which offers a bad user experience in my opinion.

I tried to learn more about the next-auth package. I saw that there was a credentials provider, which allowed to connect with a username/password, but I'm not sure if I can automatically regenerate my access token, and protect more efficiently the pages that need authentication, because if i'm understanding well, next-auth use cookie strategy.

So my question is, considering my project, is next-auth a viable solution, and does it allow me to do the same thing I already do, but in a more optimized way?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your JWT tokens in the next-auth session if they are sent in the response body.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75818894/13488990) is an example of how you can achieve this using the Credentials provider and how to access data stored in the session from the client side.
You can also find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75428838/13488990) how to protect pages that require authentification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! So I don't need my backend to use JWT strategy. Next-auth will just use this method to keep my session, right ?

Comment: yes you can manage the backend strategy tas from frontend but the best approach is to do it on both back and front

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not the one developing the backend so I can't really change it, but I'll try doing it on my side !